# Does anyone know a way to crawl a page that uses infinite scroll?

Tags: perl, web-crawler, infinite-scroll

does anyone know a way to crawl a page that uses infinite scroll? I'd like to do it with Perl, but I can't find any good user agent to do it...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your tips, sorry to take a long time to answer. Yes, I still looking at html code, to understand how the implement the infinite scroll. if I get a way around, I come here to post solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the page uses infinite scroll, that means it is using client-side scripting (JavaScript) to implement the paging. If you are using Perl to do the crawling, you are most likely issuing a server request. The returned HTML however is static, there is no JavaScript engine running in your Perl script to execute the client-side script that implements the infinite scroll functionality.

There are now two options:

1. Debug the crawled page to see how they implement the infinite scroll. It will almost certainly make an AJAX call to the server, perhaps they will allow you to also make that request. However, this solution means that your code is fixed for a single page, as each website might implement infinite scrolling differently.
2. Include a server-side JavaScript engine (such as the Chrome engine Node.js uses) and run the fetched HTML in that engine. You should then be able to simulate the infinite scrolling through some clever JavaScript code.

Comment: Nice answer, but you need to correct one statement: *"If you are using Perl to do the crawling, you issue a server request."* This is wrong. You can crawl browser-side with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

As "infinite scroll" is something that has to be realized with user-side java scripting and AJAX-alike request technologies, you'd probably have to instrumentalize a "real" browser (such as firefox) to actually simulate a user scrolling down, if you don't want to spend the time understanding how the javascript determines what to request next. Not pretty.

On a lighter note, many websites still offer you the good old paginated view if you disable javascript, so chances are you don't really need to do that. Just download the page, and look at the source code, and crawl like you would crawl any old-school blog (or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Access the site through the browser of your choice with [Selenium::Remote::Driver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Selenium::Remote::Driver).

How easily it can be made to work will depend on the website.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you [could drive Internet Explorer using Win32::OLE](http://perltricks.com/article/139/2014/12/11/Automated-Internet-Explorer-screenshots-using-Win32--OLE), taking advantage of the [DWebBrowserEvents2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface.